# PDFBox 2 Remove Text

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I'm stumbling on a problem that seems to have a number of similar questions on SO, but nothing that points to a solution with the PDFBox 2 APIs and the sort of encoding I'm dealing with. At a base level, I'm trying to remove text from a PDF that matches a regular expression. I can locate the text and the coordinates of the text without issue using a subclass of `PDFTextStripper`.

I am running into issues when using `PDFStreamParser` to actually remove. I can find text generally using the Tj operator strategy but then I am unable to actually read the text due to an encoding issue.

Is there a more straightforward way to edit the PDF to remove the text? Can I use the positions or discover the encoding to better manipulate these elements?

Comment: See here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#why-was-the-replacetext-example-removed%3F  also have a look at your file with PDFDebugger.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you for the reference. I am familiar with that. With that being said, my text is well-formed and can be found with the text stripper, including coordinates. Is there a way to remove information at a given area?

Comment: You could get the content stream, remove the part you don't like and put it back, as seen in the RemoveAllText.java example. To get the encoding you'd have to identify which font is used (In some cases it's not the one after a "Tf" command, but lets assume it is), then use this font to convert the encoded byte(s) to unicode and then match with your regular expression. The problem is that I doubt it will be in a single Tj element.